# Converting int to bytes, with confusion over significant bits and endianness

Tags: perl, endianness, pack

I am trying to implement a key derivation function from IEEE 802.11 which is described in pseudocode like this:

> *result* ← ""
> *iterations* ← ⌈*Length* / *Hashlen*⌉
> **do** *i* = 1 **to** *iterations*
>     *result* ← *result* ‖ HMAC-Hash(*K*, *i* ‖ *Label* ‖ *Context* ‖ *Length*)
> **od**
> **return** first *Length* bits of *result*, and irretrievably delete the other bits
>
> where
>
> *i* and *Length*   are encoded as 16-bit unsigned integers, represented using the bit ordering conventions of 9.2.2
> *K*, *Label*, and *Context*   are bit strings and are represented using the ordering conventions of 9.2.2
> *Hashlen* is the length, in bits, of the digest produced by Hash

And section 9.2.2 says:

> In figures, all bits within fields are numbered, from 0 to k, where the length of the field is k + 1 bits. Bits within numeric fields that are longer than a single bit are depicted in increasing order of significance, i.e., with the lowest numbered bit having the least significance. The octet boundaries within a field can be obtained by taking the bit numbers of the field modulo 8. Octets within numeric fields that are longer than a single octet are depicted in increasing order of significance, from lowest numbered bit to highest numbered bit. The octets in fields longer than a single octet are sent to the [physical layer] in order from the octet containing the lowest numbered bits to the octet containing the highest numbered bits.

I think I have written this correctly but a) Perl is not my native language, b) I have trouble getting this endian significant bits stuff, and c) I am not getting expected results. So I wanted to ensure I have properly interpreted the stuff about the unsigned integers and applied it with `pack()` correctly.

```perl
sub kdf {
    my ($self, $K, $Hash, $Context, $Length) = @_;

    my $Label = "Pairwise key expansion";
    my $Hashlen;
    my $result = "";
    my $LengthBytes = pack("S", $Length);
    my $iBytes;

    if ($Hash eq "SHA_256") {
        $Hashlen = 256;
        for (my $i = 1; $i <= ceil($Length / $Hashlen); $i++) {
            $iBytes = pack("S", $i);
            $result .= hmac_sha256($K, $iBytes . $Label . $Context . $LengthBytes);
        }

        return substr($result, 0, $Length / 8);
    }
}
```

To sum up: based on the text of section 9.2.2, and assuming `$Length` is set to 384, should `printf("%v02X", $LengthBytes)` output `01.80`, `80.01`, or (I hope not) something altogether different?!

Comment: "Octets within numeric fields that are longer than a single octet are depicted in increasing order of significance". If it applies to *i* and *Length*, then it mandates LE byte order. ([`pack "S<"`](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=11111036)) /// You can combine the concat and the packing: `pack( "S< a* a* S<", $i, $Label, $Context, $Length )` /// `for my $i ( 0 .. ceil( $Length / $Hashlen ) )` is simpler and faster.

Comment: Oof that was a dumb mistake. Still not working, but having changed the pack format to `S<` and fixed the for loop it sounds like I can safely assume my problems are elsewhere.

Comment: `S<` will be the same as `S` on a x86/x86_64, so I wasn't offering that a solution to any problem. /// The opposite byte order would be `S>`. It wouldn't be anything other than one of those two.